# How do you deal with personal security issues?

Tags: audit

How do you deal with personal security issues?

Let's say you've got reason to assume somebody with big capital may be trying to track your moves.

Early in the morning, day after confrontation, you see unexpected phone reset, some tools icon and progress bar "compiling" something. Norton does not see a problem.

Today I come home, pour some coke, look at computer screen and see cmd.exe processing couple of pages of whatever, it disappeared in less than a second, don't know why but my Win8 cmd font is smallest possible - 4px or so, Norton does not see a problem, neither do any antivirus software I have tested.

What do you do after such an incident? There's no history, there's no software able to recognize whether your computer is infected with some person-dedicated malware, how to check if it's safe?

Comment: This seems rather paranoid. It's important to stay calm. You might want to use FreeBSD instead of Windows.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. I'm not sure if this is a tech support question or a more general "how to deal with a compromised computer" question. I would wipe the computer and reinstall from backups. "Nuke from orbit"

Comment: Contact a professional in your area. This site is for information security enthusiasts and professionals to exchange knowledge, not for personal assistance.

Answer (score 1):

At this point it is recommended to wipe all hard drives(for example, using [dban](http://www.dban.org/download) )and make a fresh install of your preferred operating system(I would recommend a Linux flavour such as Ubuntu which is ideal for a former windows user).

Comment: Considering that the OP don't have any idea what is going on, wiping or changing the OS might be a short term solution but he can get infected once again. Also, someone with big capital have other means to track personal movements.